# Is it possible to join array input into a single string in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have array input like below in a intermediate AWS Step function state and I want to join that into a single string, I know `States.StringSplit` for splitting string with separator into array, does reverse of it possible with **Intrinsic functions** without writing a lambda function?

e.g: Input parameters as:

```
{
   "inputArray": ["a","b","c"],
   "joiner": "/"
}
```

I am expecting below ResultPath:

```
{"joinedValue": "a/b/c/"}
```

Or

```
{"joinedValue": "a/b/c"}
```